# Inline constructor and InjectFrom calls return Object

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

Using ValueInjecter, I often find myself writing code like this:

```
var foo1 = new Foo().InjectFrom(foo2);
```

But that, unexpectedly, causes foo1 to be of type Object, not Foo. Same with

```
var foo1 = (new Foo()).InjectFrom(foo2);
```

and

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo().InjectFrom(foo2);
```

won't compile. It's not a big deal, because I can easily do

```
var foo1 = (Foo)new Foo().InjectFrom(foo2);
```

or

```
var foo1 = new Foo();
foo1.InjectFrom(foo2);
```

and those both work as expected, but I'm curious. Why does the first way not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't use ValueInjecter, but my suppose is that `InjectFrom` method returns object value.
 And as `var` is sugar syntax, and autodefines variable type during compilation, this variable is defined as Object.
 That's why you have to use explicit type convertion to make this work for you.

Comment: Of course, I see the difference now. In the first case I'm assigning foo1 the result of the call to InjectFrom(foo2), not the constructor. Thanks, this was a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add custom extension method:

```
public static T InjectFrom<T>(this T obj, T from) //May be from should be object type
{
    return (T) obj.InjectFrom(foo2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write like this as well:

```
var foo1 = new Foo().InjectFrom(foo2) as Foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of extensions:

```
public static class ValueInjecterExtentions
{
    public static T InjectIntoNew<T,TInjection>(this object from) 
        where T: new ()
        where TInjection : Omu.ValueInjecter.Injections.IValueInjection, new()
    {
        return (T) new T().InjectFrom<TInjection>(from);
    }

    public static T InjectIntoNew<T>(this object from)
        where T : new()
    {
        return (T)new T().InjectFrom(from);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var foo = foo2.InjectIntoNew<Foo>();
```

obviously only usable with default constructor, which is often the case.